# jquery total and subtotal for each dynamic row is only calculating first row

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to build a dynamic grid style calculator so users can build up the cost of something, they can add as many rows as needed to capture all the component details. What I need to do now is make my jQuery dynamic too, so it calculates each `Total` and `Line Total` for each row that's added. As I've got the code at the moment it only works for the first row of the calculator

[image: Calculator]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.used-amount input[type="text"]')
           .on("propertychange, change, keyup, paste, input", function () {
        var usedtotal = $(this).val() * $('.used-cost input[type="text"]').val();
        $('.used-total').text(usedtotal);
    });

    $('.used-cost input[type="text"]')
           .on("propertychange, change, keyup, paste, input", function () {
        var usedtotal = $(this).val() * $('.used-amount input[type="text"]').val();
        $('.used-total').text(usedtotal);
    });

    $('.wastage-cost input[type="text"]')
           .on("propertychange, change, keyup, paste, input", function () {
        var usedtotal = $(this).val() * $('.wastage-amount input[type="text"]').val();
        $('.wastage-total').text(usedtotal);
    });

    $('.wastage-cost input[type="text"]')
           .on("propertychange, change, keyup, paste, input", function () {
        var usedtotal = $(this).val() * $('.wastage-amount input[type="text"]').val();
        $('.wastage-total').text(usedtotal);
    });

    $('.calculator input[type="text"]')
           .on("propertychange, change, keyup, paste, input", function () {
        var linetotal = 
            ($('.used-amount input[type="text"]').val()
          *  $('.used-cost input[type="text"]').val())
          + ($('.wastage-amount input[type="text"]').val()
          *  $('.wastage-cost input[type="text"]').val())
        $('.line-total').text(linetotal);
    });
});
```

and each row is a razor partial view:

```
@model TheWorkshop.Web.Models.Edit.CalculatorViewModel

<tr class="calculator-detail">
  <td class="component-type">@Html.EnumDropDownListify("ComponentType", @Model.ComponentType)</td>
  <td class="component">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedComponentId, Model.ComponentSelectList, "Select...")</td>
  <td class="used-amount">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UsedAmount)</td>
  <td class="used-cost">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UsedCost)</td>
  <td class="used-total"></td>
  <td class="wastage-amount">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.WastageAmount)</td>
  <td class="wastage-cost">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.WastageCost)</td>
  <td class="wastage-total"></td>
  <td class="line-total"></td>
</tr>
```

which I'm adding when the button is clicked

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $.get('@Url.Action("AddCalculatorRow", "Workshop", 
                new { id = Model.Id } )', function (data) {
            $(data).hide().appendTo('.calculator tbody').fadeIn(2000);
        });
    });
});
```

and the Controller

```
public ActionResult AddCalculatorRow()
{
    var components = Session.QueryOver<Component>()
                            .OrderBy(c => c.Name).Asc.List<Component>();
    var modelView = new CalculatorViewModel() { Components = components }; 

    return PartialView("_CalculatorRow", modelView);
}
```

**Edit**
I've got the Used & Cost total and the Wastage & Cost total working. But can't seem to get LineTotal working and following @JeffB's comments it now looks like this:

```
$(document)
  .on("propertychange, change, keyup, paste, input",
      '.calculator input[type="text"]', function () {
         var linetotal = 
           ($(this).parent().siblings('.used-amount').find('input').val() *    
            $(this).parent().siblings('.used-cost').find('input').val())
         + ($(this).parent().siblings('.wastage-amount').find('input').val() * 
            $(this).parent().siblings('.wastage-cost').find('input').val());
         $(this).parent().siblings('.line-total').text(usedtotal);
      });
```

**Edit 2**
That'll teach me for copy & pasting...
The mistake in my code above is that I've assigned the total of all 4 cells to a `linetotal` variable but when updating the `line-total` cell have `usedtotal`, which is nothing! Changing that to the linetotal variable fixed it and now all cells calculate correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the non-delegated version of on() that does not bind to UI elements added after the call is made.  Try changing

```
$('.used-amount input[type="text"]')
       .on("propertychange, change, keyup, paste, input", function () {
    var usedtotal = $(this).val() * $('.used-cost input[type="text"]').val();
    $('.used-total').text(usedtotal);
});
```

to

```
$(document)
       .on("propertychange, change, keyup, paste, input", 
           '.used-amount input[type="text"]', function () {
    var usedtotal = $(this).val() * $('.used-cost input[type="text"]').val();
    $('.used-total').text(usedtotal);
});
```

For more, see the section **Direct and delegated events** in

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I would add that `$('.used-total')` and `$('.used-cost')` refer to *every* one of those elements, rather than the ones associated with that line.  That will need to be converted to `$(this).nextAll('.used-total')`, or something of the sort.

Comment: @JeffB the selectors >refer to _every_ one of those elments 
exactly! nextAll does prevent latter rows updating previous, but they actually don't update their own row either. Can you suggest anything?

Comment: @SimonMartin: No, that is not true.  `$(this)` refers to the element modified, in this case `.used-amount`.  `$(this).nextAll('.used-cost')` selects the next element with class `used-cost`.  In this case, it won't work, I realize, because the input elements are children of the `td`s.  You would need: `$(this).parent().siblings('.used-cost').find('input').val()` and `$(this).parent().siblings('.used-total').text(usedtotal)`

Comment: You could also use: `$(this).closest('.calculator-detail').find('.used-cost input').val()` and `$(this).closest('.calculator-detail').find('.used-total').text(usedtotal)`

Comment: @JeffB got that working for the sub-totals. Could you put in an answer that shows how to get the linetotal working in the same way (finding it hard to follow the code in comments)